# how to keep null value in yaml file while dumping though ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have YAML file `site.yaml`:

```
Kvm_BLOCK:
  ip_address: 10.X.X.X
  property: null
  server_type: zone
```

loaded and then dumped with:

```
ruamel.yaml.dump(site_yaml, new_file, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

it becomes

```
Kvm_BLOCK:
      ip_address: 10.X.X.X
      property: 
      server_type: zone
```

how to retain this `null` value in property block

Answer (score 14):

The `null` value in YAML 1.2 (constructed as Python's `None`) can be represented as `null`, `Null`, `NULL` and `~`, as specified [here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071).

[Additionally](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786563):

> Nodes with empty content are interpreted as if they were plain scalars with an empty value. Such nodes are commonly resolved to a “null” value.

Therefore your `null` value is not gone, it is just represented differently by the default representation for `null` in `ruamel.yaml` when using `RoundTripDump`. If you load that output again, you once more get a `None` as value for the key `property`

---

If that is not to your liking you can change the output for **all** `None`/`null` values by doing:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml_str = """\
Kvm_BLOCK:
  ip_address: 10.X.X.X
  property: null
  server_type: zone
"""


def my_represent_none(self, data):
    return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', u'NULL')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.representer.add_representer(type(None), my_represent_none)

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which will dump:

```
Kvm_BLOCK:
  ip_address: 10.X.X.X
  property: NULL
  server_type: zone
```

You can get finer grained control by creating different classes in Python (`NULL`, `Null`, `null`, etc. ) and have different representers for each of them (much in the same way that the `string` subclasses in `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.py` are used to represent a string in different ways (double quoted, single quoted, literal block style scalar). The problem is that you cannot subclass `NoneType` so this is not so easily done transparently as with the string scalars.

Comment: As I understand it, this change would cause `None` to be dumped as `NULL` in all cases (including empty documents). Is there a way to cause this behavior based on the context? e.g. only on mapping values.

Comment: That kind of context is available to the emitter, and although accessible from a representer, that state might not change in time. You would probably be safer to  override methods on the emitter ( like `expect_block_mapping_value()`)